# How to annotate an optional parameter using Google Closure Compiler?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, google-closure-compiler

I am very new to Google Closure Compiler (GCC). I am confused on how to make it show a parameter as optional...

Here is part of my code:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} name The event name
 * @param {Date} date1 The start date (If alone, the single date) of the event
 * @param {Date} date2 The end date of the event
 */
function getEventLink (name,date1,date2) {
    // code here
}
```

I want to have `date2` be optional... I found a helpful [page on the Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler), but I didn't see and option for optional... is it possible? If so, how would I do it?

I've tried doing:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} name The event name
 * @param {Date} date1 The start date (If alone, the single date) of the event
 * @param {Date|undefined} date2 The end date of the event
 */
function getEventLink (name,date1,date2) {
    // code here
}
```

Also, with `null` instead of `undefined`, but neither seemed to work...

Comment: In general, I'm pretty sure that JavaScript doesn't let you make arguments that aren't the last or the group starting from the back optional, unless when you call it you explicitly say `null` or `undefined` etc. in the function call

Comment: I know JavaScript doesn't do it, but do you know if with the `GCC` I can have a parameter be `optional`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Closure Compiler relies on annotations to do its work. Because JavaScript has no syntax for types these have to be written as comments in the source files.

These comments are written using JSDoc and even though GCC has come with its own tags over the years (e.g. `@polymer` isn't a "native" JSDoc tag), it does support JSDoc types expressions. (And JSDoc does support the Google Closure Type System in its type expressions too.)

#### Annotation? Expression? What?!

A simple example will clarify:

```js
/**
 * @param {string|number} x
 */
const a = x => x;
```

This is the annotation: `@param {string|number} x`. It is information about a thing:

1. it is a parameter
2. its name is `x`
3. its type is either a string or a number

This is the type expression: `{string|number}`. It is information about the type of a thing.

#### Optional parameters in JavaScript

As you know JavaScript allows to specify default values for parameters in the function signature:

```js
const a = (x=1, y=2, z=3) => x + y + z;
```

These default values are used if and only if `undefined` is passed either implicitly or explicitly:

```js
a();
//=> 6

a(undefined, undefined, 20);
//=> 23

a(null, null, 20);
//=> 20 (null doesn't trigger the default value and is coerced to 0)
```

#### Optional parameters in JSDoc

There are two annotations possible for an optional parameter. Just pick the one you like:

```
/** @param {number=} x */
```

or

```
/** @param {number} [x] */
```

However there is only one for an optional parameter *with* a default value:

```
/** @param {number} [x=1] */
```

#### Optional parameters with GCC

Even though `a(undefined, undefined, 20)` is technically possible in JavaScript, it is however a poor developer experience and GCC *may* complain.

Optional parameters without declared default values in the function signature should be last otherwise GCC will issue a warning.

In this example `z` is the only non-optional parameter however it is the last parameter:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} [x=1]
 * @param {number} [y=2]
 * @param {number} z
 */
const a = (x, y, z) => (x ?? 1) + (y ?? 2) + z;

a(undefined, undefined, 20);
//=> 23
```

GCC output:

```
JSC_OPTIONAL_ARG_AT_END: optional arguments must be at the end at line 11 character 10
const a = (x, y, z) => (x ?? 1) + (y ?? 2) + z;
          ^
```

This is of course not an issue if all parameters are optional. These examples are all OK:

```js
/**
 * @param {number} [x=1]
 * @param {number} [y=2]
 * @param {number} [z=3]
 */
const a = (x, y, z=3) => (x ?? 1) + (y ?? 2) + z;
```

or

```js
/**
 * @param {number} [x=1]
 * @param {number} [y=2]
 * @param {number} [z=3]
 */
const a = (x, y, z) => (x ?? 1) + (y ?? 2) + (z ?? 3);
```

or

```js
/**
 * @param {number} [x=1]
 * @param {number} [y=2]
 * @param {number} [z=3]
 */
const a = (x=1, y=2, z=3) => x + y + z;
```

---

**Further readings**

- [JSDoc Cheat Sheet](https://gist.github.com/customcommander/5206dcb44670e34f6923b62c1781e1d2). (Disclosure: I am the author)

Comment: Very helpful here; thank you. I've been a little lost on the usage of multiple parameters with descriptions in this way; it only shows the description of the first parameter for me. Is that normal, just a limitation of JSDoc / GCC? Thank you